# python pillow (better PIL) encoding check bug

Tags: python, encoding, isinstance, python-imaging-library

I've just installed a Pillow package to my virtualenv. Doing this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
ImageFont.load_path('some_path')
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/net/isilonP/public/rw/homes/cbl_adm/.virtualenvs/chembl_webservices/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 264, in load_path
    if not isinstance(filename, "utf-8"):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

And indeed, if you check official gihub repository (https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/ImageFont.py#L264), you can see this construct:

```
if not isinstance(filename, "utf-8"):
    ...
```

My question is: How do I replace it with something which actually works?

Comment: File a bug report with the project? Pillow is under very active development.

Comment: Done! https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone overlooked testing that method; the correct incantation is:

```
if not isinstance(filename, str):
    # ...
```

because the rest of the code proceeds to turn it *into* a `str`, for both Python 2 and Python 3.

I've issued a [pull request](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/pull/306), after talking with the maintainer on IRC.

Update: the patch has now been merged.

Comment: Yup, saw that *after* I pushed it. Travelling by train, the connectivity and opportunities to code wax and wane. :-)